# Storing TextField values to an array

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm working on a program in Javafx, which allows the user to input values in TextFields. Additionaly, there is an empty Choicebox, where a value beginning from "1" is added. Everytime he presses the "Submit" button, the TextFields also get cleared and he can input another set of values in said TextFields.

Let's say he inputs five sets of values and presses "Submit", I'd like to have those values stored in an array, so when he chooses a number in the ChoiceBox, the corresponding values are shown again in the TextFields.

For this I need to store them in an array. Below is the eventhandler for the buttonclick

```
    private void next(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

    double c_stueck = Double.parseDouble(stueck.getText());
    double c_pr_pro_einheit = Double.parseDouble(pr_pro_eh.getText());
    double c_betrag = Double.parseDouble(betrag.getText());
    String c_bezeichnung=bezeichnung.getText().toString();
    c_betrag += c_stueck * c_pr_pro_einheit;
    String c_betragval = String.valueOf(c_betrag);
    betrag.setText(c_betragval);

     stueck.setText("");
     pr_pro_eh.setText("");
     bezeichnung.setText("");

    for(int j=0; j<=49;j++)
    {
        arr_stueck[j]=  c_stueck;
        arr_pr_pro_eh[j]= c_pr_pro_einheit;
        arr_bezeichnung[j]= c_bezeichnung;
        position.getItems().add(j);

    }




}
```

The problem lies herein, that everytime the eventhandler is fired, the array is reset. Is there a way to save the increment, so the next time the button is pressed, the for loop continues from the last increment?

Comment: Which array? There seem to be three arrays referenced in the event handler, plus a list. What is the definition of the array? Where is it declared? How is it initialized and where?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't specific - The three arrays are for the three values from the TextFields. All three values from the TextFields should be saved in the array. The list is just the ChoiceBox, meaning everytime the eventhandler is fired (everytime values are entered in the Textfields, the list should add a number "j" to the ChoiceBox.

The arrays are declared outside the eventhandler, I'm still not sure what datatypes I should use for the arrays, but that's not the problem

Comment: OK, then why are you doing it 50 times for each press of the button? You fill the first 50 places of the array with the same value each time you do that.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, I just want to fill each place with the values that are entered in the TextFields, but pressing firing the eventhandler resets the array anyways right?

Comment: Look at your `for` loop. What do you think it is doing? Remember that the entire loop is done each time you press the button.

Comment: You are asking to fix a solution which is not the correct solution to the problem you are trying to solve. You shouldn't be using arrays for this at all. Define a class to represent each item in the `ChoiceBox` (it will have `stueck`, `prProEinheit`, and `bezeichnung` fields), and each time the user presses enter, create an object from that class and insert it into the `ChoiceBox`'s items list. Then you can just register a listener with the choice box's selected item and update the text fields.

Comment: Yeah... it is filling the array with the same values which were entered in the TextField. Should I make the for loop outside the button?

Comment: @Ajay_C Why is there a `for` loop at all?

Comment: @James_D Hmm, you're right, I'll try that with an additional class.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem